# Identify via Youtube data API whether advertisements can be displayed on/before/next to a specific video

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, ads, youtube-data-api

Is there a possibility to check via the Youtube data API whether advertisements can be displayed with a specific video?

I understand contentDetails.licensedContent only shows whether a video was uploaded to and then claimed by that same partner. licensedContent false-videos might still be displayed with ads due to 3rd party rights claims and licensedContent true-videos might just simply not want ads.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [ContentOwnerAdvertisingOption](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/contentOwnerAdvertisingOptions#resource) API, making use of the GET operation in order to retrieve various information provided by the API. In the result you will see a Boolean type parameter **adsOnEmbeds** that indicates whether the partner can display ads when videos run in an embedded player.

Hope that answers your question.